# Formatting DateTime property in DataTables jquery plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime, datatable

I want to show just the year of my DateTime string in my DataTable. Right now I have something like this "1987-02-13T00:00:00".

The DateTime is a property called "ReleaseDate" which exists in my Movies table. I use an API to get this data using Ajax calls.

```
data: "releaseDate"
```

This retrieves and shows the data from my API unformatted.
I tried using the render function to add some formatting, but have been unsuccesful, as I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'year' of undefined"

```
render: function(data) { return data.value.year; }
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach. Before I started using DataTables, i was able to display just the year without problems using standard razor view syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Converting data to Date Type & return year using [getFullYear()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp)

```
"render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);

        return date.getFullYear();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! I was sure it would be possible using the render property.